# QGIS 2.10.1. GRASS Algorithm Processing

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing

While selecting the GRASS algorithms 'Processing algorithm: v.to.points - Create points along input lines'

The error message came up:

> The specified GRASS GIS 7 folder does not contain a valid set of GRASS
>   GIS 7 modules. Please, go to the Processing settings dialog, and check
>   that the GRASS GIS 7 folder is correctly configured.

Please suggest me the solution to run the GRASS algorithms?

Comment: I have 2.10.1 (running under Ubuntu 12.04) as well and none the Processing Toolbox GRASS 7 modules run in this. According to bits and pieces I've read QGIS 2.12 is due out in the next week and this should fix the GRASS problems. In the meanwhile perhaps the 'QChainage' plugin will do what you want?

Comment: Is the same if you try running `v.to.points` from **GRASS commands** instead of **GRASS GIS 7 commands**? Normally for me, _GRASS GIS 7_ commands do not work.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. The 'QChainage' plugin is working fine @nhopton.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have tried 'v.to.point' from GRASS commands but its not functional, hopefully the issue gets resolved in updated QGIS V2.12. @Joseph

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to update the "Processing" plugin via Plugin manager. It got recently fixed, be sure to have the plugins updated and the updated "Processing" activated.